# PostgreSQL BETWEEN AND Two FIELD

Tags: postgresql

i need help i'm peruvian, question:

```
SELECT fechas,dni
  FROM asistencia.reporteasistenciaview
  WHERE fechas between '03-03-2014' and '17-03-2014'
    AND dni = '44845551'
  order by fechas ASC
```

Comment: If the question is about converting a string to a date, look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html ex: to_date('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')

Comment: @Glenn please don't link to outdated versions. Use `current` instead of the version number in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the question is, but use ISO 8601 date-format `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is the [recommended format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) for date-input and works with *any* locale:

```
SELECT fechas, dni
FROM   asistencia.reporteasistenciaview
WHERE  fechas BETWEEN '2014-03-03' AND '2014-03-17'
AND    dni = '44845551'
ORDER  BY fechas;
```